# Redirects within hook_user_login

Tags: 7, hooks, users, redirection

I'm writing a module that redirects the user on login and am having trouble getting anything to work. Here is what I tried within [hook_user_login](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7):

**submission.info**

```
name = Submission
description = Handles Redirect to node/add/page on Login 
core = 7.x
```

**submission.module**

```
function submission_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  //$_REQUEST['destination'] = 'node/add/page';
  //$GLOBALS['destination'] = 'node/add/page';
  //$edit['redirect'] = 'node/add/page';
  drupal_goto('node/add/page');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change `drupal_goto` with $_GET['destination'], e.g.:

```
function submission_user_login(&$edit, $account) {

   // Redirect user to to desired location.
   $_GET['destination'] = 'node/add/page';
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: this works. but i had to remove the two single quotes.

Comment: @Rupesh : Thanks to edit the answer, it was typo I guess. Emanegux glad that could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Login Destination](https://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module to redirect user after login. This module have many customization for redirecton of user.
For more info go through the documentation of module.

Comment: As you can see in the question, I've already tried this. Please edit the question if this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module to do this very easily..

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules).

OR

You can use below code to redirect inside hook_user_login implementation ..

```
function YOURMODULENAME_user_login(&$edit, $account)  {
  $GLOBALS['destination'] = 'node/add/page';
}
```

You also need to implement hook_drupal_goto_alter to perform redirect

```
/**
 * Implements hook_drupal_goto_alter
 */
function YOURMODULENAME_drupal_goto_alter(&$path, &$options, &$http_response_code) {
  // Note that this functionality cannot be backported do 6.x as Drupal 6 does
  // not call drupal_alter for drupal_goto.

  // This actually may be used also by templates.
  if (isset($GLOBALS['destination'])) {
    $destination = $GLOBALS['destination'];

    // alter drupal_goto
    if (is_array($destination)) {
      $path = $destination[0];
      $options = array();
      if (count($destination) > 1) {
        $options = $destination[1];
      }
    }
    else {
      $path = $destination;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: drupal_goto also does not work, even with a fresh d7 installation, and I do not want to rely on admin site configuration through contributed modules until I have exhausted all my options within the core APIs.

Comment: Did you clear your cache after code implementation ? Can you make sure your hook is firing using drupal_set_message("Hello"); inside your function ?

Comment: Yes, my cache was cleared after implementing drupal_goto('node/add/page'); and it still does not work.

Comment: Do you see drupal_set_message("Hello"); getting triggered and message "Hello" has been displayed in screen when logged in ? Is your custom module enabled ?

Comment: yes, I have tested the hook before posting this question. the issue this concerns is redirect not working within a custom module on fresh install.

Comment: what is the name of your module?

Comment: I updated the question to include more detail.

Comment: See updated code that works :-)